# Realiza un batch de nombre Ej2.bat que realice las siguientes acciones usando la estructura IF ELSE

Tags: cmd, windows10

Un batch que realice las siguientes acciones usando la estructura IF ELSE

• Pedir al usuario un número del 1 al 10 por pantalla

• Que el programa le diga al usuario si ese número es primo o no

Lo que pasa es que siempre entra en el ElSE de no primo, cuando se le introduzca un numero que si es primo, por lo tanto no se si mi código esta bien estructurado la forma en la que pregunto o me falta alguna otra comprobación, teniendo en cuenta que solo puedo usar los IF-ELSE.

Aquí mi código

```
@echo off

set /p num="escribe un numero del 1 al 10: "

set /a division=num/1
set /a division2=num/2

echo %division2%
echo %division%

IF %division%==%num% (
    IF %division2%==0 (
        echo Es primo
    ) ELSE (
        echo No primo
    )
) 

:end
```

Comment: Hola Andres, bienvenido, a tu pregunta le falta algo... la pregunta, el programa no da la respuesta adecuada?, te arroja un error?, en fin, así como está redactada tu... no-pregunta, será difícil ayudarte, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta para aclarar que necesitas, de paso mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso

Comment: Pedona mi desconocimiento del lenguaje, esto ***IF %division%==%num% (***, es un bucle for?

Comment: debes crear un bucle que itere desde 2 hasta la raíz cuadrada del numero recibido, dentro del ***if***, retornas "**no es Primo**" , elimina el ***else***, y si la ejecución sale delbucle retornas "**Es Primo**"